# Why is it doing that! (SCALING PROBLEM)

Tags: modeling, transforms

Why is it scaling using the edge's position that i selected with. (can't really explain it...)

VIDEO >> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G0NNw5lPUEsauMDGTBGmUKnV0mQj1mDl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Also please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Comment: In the Transform Pivot Point panel you've chosen Active Element, so it's going to scale with the active edge as center of the scale, witch to Median Point instead